# Javascript form validating

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am having a bit of trouble with my form validation JavaScript. I have two working form validations but one is practically no longer needed. So I am trying to combined them into one function. The problem is that if I try I no longer get the input background color working. Can any one show me what I am doing wrong?

```
     //onload callback function
     function main() {
        console.log("in main function");
        var myForm  = document.getElementById("payment");
        myForm.addEventListener("submit",validateForm);
      }

      //validate callback function 
      function validateForm(event) {
        var formValid = true;
        var myForm = document.getElementById("payment"); 
        console.log("in validateForm function")
        if (myForm.first_name.value == "") {
            formValid = false;
            //display error message 
            document.getElementById("firstname").className += " formInvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid
            //stop form from submitting
            event.preventDefault();
        } 
        else
            document.getElementById("firstname").className += " formvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid

        if (myForm.last_name.value == "") {
            formValid = false;
            //display error message 
            document.getElementById("lastname").className += " formInvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid
            //stop form from submitting
            event.preventDefault();
        } 

        else
            document.getElementById("lastname").className += " formvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid

        if (myForm.email.value == "") {
            formValid = false;
            //display error message 
            document.getElementById("email").className += " formInvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid
            //stop form from submitting
            event.preventDefault();
        } 

        else
            document.getElementById("email").className += " formvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid


        if (myForm.message.value == "") {
            formValid = false;
            //display error message 
            document.getElementById("message").className += " formInvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid
            //stop form from submitting
            event.preventDefault();
        } 

            else
            document.getElementById("message").className += " formvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid


      }








     //onload callback function
     function main2() {
        console.log("in main2 function");
        var myForm2  = document.getElementById("payment");
        myForm2.addEventListener("submit",validateinput);
      }



// form validation, makes sure that the user inputs the correct data types.         
    function validateinput(b){
    var myForm2 = document.getElementById("payment"); 
    console.log("in validateinput function")
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
    var message = document.getElementById('message').value;

    var emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    var firstnameFilter = /^([" "a-zA-Z])+$/;
    var lastnameFilter = /^([" "a-zA-Z])+$/;
    var messageFilter = /^([" "a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+$/;
    var formValid = true;


    if (!emailFilter.test(email)) {
    formValid = false;
    //display error message
    alert('Please enter a valid e-mail address.');
    //stop form from submitting
    b.preventDefault();
    return false;
    }


    if (!firstnameFilter.test(firstname)) {
    formValid = false;
    alert('Please correct your first name.');
    //stop form from submitting
    b.preventDefault();
    return false;
    }



    if (!lastnameFilter.test(lastname)) {
    formValid = false;
    //display error message
    alert('Please correct your last name.');
    //stop form from submitting
    b.preventDefault();
    return false;
    }



    if (!messageFilter.test(message)) {
    formValid = false;
    //display error message
    alert('Please correct your message.');
    //stop form from submitting
    b.preventDefault();
    return false;
    }



    alert('Your message has beeen submitted')
    return true;
    }
```

Both load in the same way and have a onload in the html body tag for `main();` `main2();` and are from the same script, as you can see the top function `validateForm(event)` just changes the calssname so my css can change the background for vaild or invaild. This works fine but only for a empty input "". I don't know how to change it to `/^([" "a-zA-Z])+$/;` I have another function which looks for exact input then displays the alert message which I want to keep.

I tried to merge them into one function but i have to enter a email first then a name then a last name **in that order** or the background color / class name change does not happen. I assume the code is being read from top to bottom. And also the `document.getElementById("lastname").className += " formInvalid";` is not working. Please can anybody help me fix this.

```
     //onload callback function
     function main2() {
        console.log("in main2 function");
        var myForm2  = document.getElementById("payment");
        myForm2.addEventListener("submit",validateinput);
      }



// form validation, makes sure that the user inputs the correct data types.         
    function validateinput(b){
    var myForm2 = document.getElementById("payment"); 
    console.log("in validateinput function")
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
    var message = document.getElementById('message').value;

    var emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/g;
    var firstnameFilter = /^([" "a-zA-Z])+$/g;
    var lastnameFilter = /^([" "a-zA-Z])+$/g;
    var messageFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+$/g;
    var formValid = true;


    if (!emailFilter.test(email)) {
    formValid = false;
    //display error message
    document.getElementById("email").className += " formInvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid
    alert('Please enter a valid e-mail address.');
    //stop form from submitting
    b.preventDefault();
    return false;
    }

    else
    document.getElementById("email").className += " formvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid


    if (!firstnameFilter.test(firstname)) {
    formValid = false;
    //display erroe message
    document.getElementById("firstname").className += " formInvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid
    alert('Please correct your first name.');
    //stop form from submitting
    b.preventDefault();
    return false;
    }

    else
    document.getElementById("firstname").className += " formvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid


    if (!lastnameFilter.test(lastname)) {
    formValid = false;
    //display error message
    document.getElementById("lastname").className += " formInvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid
    alert('Please correct your last name.');
    //stop form from submitting
    b.preventDefault();
    return false;
    }

    else
    document.getElementById("lastname").className += " formvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid


    if (!messageFilter.test(message)) {
    formValid = false;
    //display error message
    document.getElementById("message").className += " formInvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid
    alert('Please correct your message.');
    //stop form from submitting
    b.preventDefault();
    return false;
    }

    else
    document.getElementById("message").className += " formvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid

    alert('Your message has beeen submitted')
    return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: Do check your code before asking a question! http://www.javascriptlint.com/

```
// form validation, makes sure that the user inputs the correct data types.         
    function validateinput(b){
    var myForm2 = document.getElementById("payment"); 
    console.log("in validateinput function")
```

Missing `;` on function `console.log`

```
var formValid = true;


    if (!emailFilter.test(email)) {
    formValid = false;
    //display error message
    document.getElementById("email").className += " formInvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid
    alert('Please enter a valid e-mail address.');
    //stop form from submitting
    b.preventDefault();
    return false;
    }

    else
```

Missing `{` after `else`

`.......`

```
    document.getElementById("email").className += " formvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid


    if (!firstnameFilter.test(firstname)) {
    formValid = false;
    //display erroe message
    document.getElementById("firstname").className += " formInvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid
    alert('Please correct your first name.');
    //stop form from submitting
    b.preventDefault();
    return false;
    }

else
```

Missing `{` after `else`

```
    document.getElementById("lastname").className += " formvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid


    if (!messageFilter.test(message)) {
    formValid = false;
    //display error message
    document.getElementById("message").className += " formInvalid"; //add the class .formInvalid
    alert('Please correct your message.');
    //stop form from submitting
    b.preventDefault();
    return false;
    }
```

Missing `}` after Function Body